# T-test with large standard deviation

Tags: t-test, standard-deviation

I have performed a two-sample t test. I am comparing census block groups with a bike lane in the vicinity (n = 608) with block groups with no bike lane (n = 453), in terms of a population deprivation index ranging from -1 to 1.

The results show me that the index is lower (= less poverty) (M = -0.035, SD = 0.831) in block groups with bike lanes than in block groups without bike lanes (M = 0.072, SD = 0.662), t(855.53) = 2.275, p < .05.

One reviewer is telling me that the M value is very close to zero (and very high SD) to be able to reach such conclusions. Should I accept his/her interpretation or should I consider that my conclusion (census block groups are different at the .95 level) is right?

Comment: What is the meaning of "sma" in your title?  Why do you report the SD, when the *standard error* is the relevant statistic?

Comment: Sorry, "sma" stands for "small means", but it was cut. I will edit the title. Regarding SD: I followed indications from APA https://www.socscistatistics.com/tutorials/ttest/default.aspx.

Comment: I ran a t-test and got quite different results (although it's possible I made a mistake.) Can you check your numbers? 
y1 <- scale(rnorm(608)) * 0.831 - 0.035

y2 <- scale(rnorm(453)) * 0.662 - 0.072

d <- data.frame(y = c(y1, y2), x = c(rep(0, 608), rep(1, 453)))

t.test(d$y ~ d$x)

Comment: @JeremyMiles check your code; it looks to me like maybe some of it has been interpreted as markdown formatting.

Comment: This should work as intended though: `t.test(scale(rnorm(608)) * 0.831 - 0.035, scale(rnorm(453)) * 0.662 - 0.072)`; it suggests that $p=0.42$. @miguel - how did you get your t-value and p-value?

Comment: Unfortunately, your reviewer doesn't seem to appreciate that these are sample SDs and not SEs of the means: the value of the SD is *completely irrelevant* in a t-test, so their reference to it indicates they are misintepreting it as an SE.  BTW, your DF of 855.53 suggests you are using some kind of unequal-variances version of the t-test: you ought to state which.  And merely reporting "p < 0.05" does a disservice to readers who have stronger standards than the 0.05 threshold: it is far better to report the actual p-value.  (If you think APA says otherwise, ignore them!)